# How to word either A or B?

Tags: claims

If I'm wording a claim for my cool device and I want to express that either option A (squarish flange type 1) or option B (roundish flange type 2) can be attached to my design, or any other type, how do I word that?

Comment: Is any flange required for patentability? Is the structure of "my desgin" different when flange 1 is used vs flange 2? It may be that your broadest claims should not have any flange at all as a needed element.

Comment: What if a flange is required, but it is best for clarity to describe the various options about what type of flange can be used. For instance, a dresser with drawers has a handle on each drawer, but there are a few kinds of handles that will work.

Comment: What I meant by required, is required for patentablity not required for use or operation. An innovative door will need hinges to be used. If there is a patentable innovation about the door that is independent of the type of hinge then the broadest claim just specifies the structural features of the door. Maybe a part of what is special about the door is that it has locations on its edge adapted for quick connection to a hinge. We are still specifying the door when we describe the part of the door that is set up for hinge connection.